"pipe is not a function" problem using uploadBytes to save an image to Firebase
I would like my Web application, front and back ends written in TypeScript, to allow a Web user to select a PNG and then have it sent to the server and saved as a blob in Firebase such that it gives me a URL I can then send back to the Web app client upon demand. All is fine on the client side. I prompt the user for an image file, use FileReader's readAsDataURL method to convert it to a properly encoded data URL string (looks like 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA...'), and send a proper request that is received on my Express server. My server receives the proper string and then invokes my updateProfilePic method shown below, which converts it to a File/Blob and tries to use uploadBytes to send bytes to storage. The problem is uploadBytes fails. It produces an error saying:
...\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:650
        body.stream().pipe(dest);
                ^
source-map-support.js:475
TypeError: body.stream(...).pipe is not a function

Here is my 1st try:
// NODE LIBRARIES
import { getDownloadURL, getStorage, ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";

export class MyImageUploader {
    async updateProfilePic(
        userId: string,
        picDataURL: string
    ): Promise<string> {
        let imgFileName = userId + "ProfilePic.png";
        let fetchResponse: Response = await fetch(picDataURL);
        let imgBlob: Blob = await fetchResponse.blob();
        let imgFile = new File([imgBlob], imgFileName, { type: 'image/png' });
        const storage = getStorage();
        const userPicRef = ref(storage, imgFileName);
        await uploadBytes(userPicRef, imgFile).then(async (snapshot) => {
            let imgDownloadURL : string = await getDownloadURL(userPicRef);
            return imgDownloadURL;
        });
        return "none";
    }
}

So, instead of sending the imgFile (a File) to uploadBytes, which I've seen done in numerous online tutorials, I tried sending the Blob (which I've also seen), and it produces the same error. One online message board said one should use Readable to send a stream, so I did:
// NODE LIBRARIES
import { getDownloadURL, getStorage, ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";
import { Readable } from 'stream';

export class MyImageUploader {
    async updateProfilePic(
        userId: string,
        picDataURL: string
    ): Promise<string> {
        let imgFileName = userId + "ProfilePic.png";
        let fetchResponse: Response = await fetch(picDataURL);
        let imgBlob: Blob = await fetchResponse.blob();
        let imgFile = new File([imgBlob], imgFileName, { type: 'image/png' });
        const storage = getStorage();
        const userPicRef = ref(storage, imgFileName);
        let imgArrayBuffer = await imgBlob.arrayBuffer();
        const buffer = Buffer.from(imgArrayBuffer);
        const readableStream = Readable.from(buffer);

        await uploadBytes(userPicRef, readableStream).then(async (snapshot) => {
            let imgDownloadURL : string = await getDownloadURL(userPicRef);
            return imgDownloadURL;
        });
        return "none";
    }
}

But this does not compile as it flags readableStream as not being a valid type to send to uploadBytes, even though this is recommended by Google AI when I ask for help, the syntax error says:

error TS2345: Argument of type 'Readable' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Blob | ArrayBuffer | Uint8Array'.
Type 'Readable' is missing the following properties from type 'Uint8Array': BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, buffer, byteLength, byteOffset, and 26 more.**

This is quite frustrating because I have carefully followed examples provided by others and have carefully read the API documentation and have carefully read others who have had such errors and I feel I am so close but am simply stuck. Any help would be appreciated.
I tried both example methods I've provided and was expecting image bytes to be written to Firebase storage such that a URL could then be used to access the image.

Please edit the question to show the imports for the various functions being used here so we know which libraries or SDKs you're using.  Ideally we should be able to take your code, copy it, and reproduce the same result.

The firebase/storage library is meant for use on web frontends, not nodejs backends.  I don't recommend putting any effort into making that work on nodejs.  For nodejs, you should use the Firebase Admin SDK, which implements a thin wrapper around @google-cloud/storage.

While I appreciate there might be a better way of doing this using a different, more up to date approach/library, I have a whole lot of working, deployed code in my existing application using my stated approach and would prefer not to have to rewrite thousands of lines of code if I don't have to. So, the question is do I really have to use the admin approach? Is there another fix that suits my perhaps somewhat outdated approach? That would save me an enormous headache.

I don't know.  I just know exactly what I would do for the easiest and least problematic coding, and in this case, firebase/storage is definitely not that.  As I mentioned before, it's meant for frontend web apps, which is not what you're showing here.  It might never work at all the way you're going with it.  You'll have to ask yourself which is the bigger headache.

Thanks for the help. In the end what I did it take a different route. I decided to turn the image into encoded text and send that text, which I then stored in the database as a simple string just like all the other data.
